# How To Remove Anydesk Software In Ubantu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

```
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_deb_anydesk_com_-jammy.list (Component)
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_ftp_osuosl_org_pub_mariadb_repo_5_5_ubuntuprecise-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

This Error Comming so please how to remove?

Comment: Read the error message; it tells you the file & line number in that file that contains badly formatted data.  The directory (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) is empty normally, so the error has been added to your system by someone with `sudo` rights... As we cannot read the contents of that file (*only seeing what you provide*) we cannot provide specific help.

Comment: not solve this issue please help me.